# When running rake cucumber:ok I get errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, capybara

Here is my features/creating_projects.feature from following chapter 2-3 in Rails 3 in Action

[image]

Here is what I get when running rake cucumber:ok --trace:

[image]

I have a feeling I'm missing a dependency for Cucumber or a dependency for a dependency of Cucumber?

here is my Gemfile also:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem too, and removed the `--strict` in cucumber.yml as suggested by Justin Soong in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449248/cucumber-command-failed-with-status-1-with-rake-features).